NetSuite Saved Search Formulas - Relative Date Ranges
I'm trying to write a formula for my saved search for # of form submits for our online client forms embedded into our website.
I want one column to show "last week"'s totals and one column to show "this week"'s totals for direct comparison.
The closest I've got so far is: CASE WHEN {NUMBERSUBMITS} = {LASTWEEK} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
I know this definitely isn't right but I can't really get any closer.  I got a "field not found" error with this one.
